# Does Eclipse allow find breakpoint on xml file?

Tags: xml, eclipse, debugging, breakpoints

I have a project with many configuration xml files.
Is possible in Eclipse debugger put some kind of breakpoint so I can found if some node of xml file was read (and also need name of class) or not?
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well you have 2 options AFAICS:

1. If the project uses JAXB or Castor or some other form of XML marshalling into Java objects, all you have to do is look into the Java classes that match your XML files, find the mathcing class/method for the xml tag you want to breakpoint/debug, and debug the corresponding Java code.
2. Use [http://www.oxygenxml.com/eclipse_plugin.html"](http://www.oxygenxml.com/eclipse_plugin.html), Oxiegen XML Plugin for Eclipse.