# XML breakpoint eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, debugging, breakpoints, mybatis

It's there any way to add a break point in a XML file in order to debug? I'm having a small problem with myBatis XML file where I sort the datebase and I want to see where the problem is.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Does Eclipse allow find breakpoint on xml file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7388162/does-eclipse-allow-find-breakpoint-on-xml-file)